# Develop a plugin for outputting data in a loop

Tags: plugin-development

I am looking to develop a plugin which out put the data in a loop Or that plugin would populate the array data with template tag. Could anyone please help me or share a doc link.﻿

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please have a look at the "Template Variables" section of the documentation:
http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/variables

The template variables are the containers of data which you can access from your twig templates using `craft.yourPluginName.yourPluginVariableFunctionName`

Let's say you want to loop through 3 different items in an array from your Plugin. Your Plugin variables file might look like this:

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

class PluginNameVariable
{
    public function data()
    {
        return array('one', 'two', 'three');
    }
}
```

In your template you can now "fetch" this data like this - in a loop:

```
{% for item in craft.pluginName.data %}
    {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

*Please not this code is not tested*